# Where is com.example.android.apis.R?

Tags: android, api, graphics, camera, package

So I am trying to work through the example here:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/SurfaceViewOverlay.html

and on the last import line it says

```
//Need the following import to get access to the app resources, since this
//class is in a sub-package.
import com.example.android.apis.R;
```

Question is where do I get the package that contains this? I found very little info online and obviously don't have it already since it's underlined red when I type it. I know this is probly a noob question but hey we all start somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run this example using the android sample app.

To install and run the Android Sample apps follow the instructions here:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/get.html

> To help you get started quickly, the Android SDK includes a variety of
>   sample code and tutorials that illustrate key concepts and techniques
>   of Android application development. For example, the samples show the
>   structure of the manifest file and the use of activities, services,
>   resources, intents, content providers, and permissions. They also show
>   how to add specialized capabilities to your apps, such as Bluetooth
>   and Contacts integration, multiple screens support, Live Wallpaper,
>   and more.

Comment: Thanks, now I have it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

That R file is simply the R file of your project. So it will be `your.project.main.package.R` depending on the package attribute of the `<mainfest>` tag in your AndroidManifest.xml.

So if you have imported the project sample from the SDK, the R file would be in the same package as the example, i.e. `com.example.android.apis`.

However, if you are using the code in your own project as I assume is the case because you have mentioned the import remains unresolved, then you have to import the R file for your own project. Note that you will also have to import the required resources (layouts, drawables, etc) into your project from the sample.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting this error because I needed to add the:

`C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-18\libs\maps.jar`

to the Libraries tab in the BuildPath section of "right-click over project" / Properties.